# Serialise list of objects to single JSON object, with property as key

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Is it possible, using [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), to use one of the properties of a class that is being serialised (via a collection) as the key for that class?

For example, take the following classes in C#

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string UniqueId { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class MyCollection : List<MyClass>
{ }
```

If I run the following to serialise the collection...

```
var col = new MyCollection() {
    new MyClass { UniqueId = "First", Value = "This") },
    new MyClass { UniqueId = "Second", Value = "That") }
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(col);
```

This will result in the following JSON, with an array containing each `MyClass`.

```
[
  {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  {
    "UniqueId": "Second",
    "Value": "That"
  }
]
```

**Is there any way to force Newtonsoft to create the following instead, where an object (rather than array) is created with each class referenced by the `UniqueId` property as the key?**

```
{
  "First":
  {
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Second":
  {
    "Value": "That"
  }
}
```

Or if easier...

```
{
  "First":
  {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Second":
  {
    "UniqueId": "Second",
    "Value": "That"
  }
}
```

I'm aware that using a `Dictionary<>` will result in what I want, by using the same value from the property as the key... however, this is **unordered** and I need the `List<>` so it's in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) can be used to keep the order of the items added, or a [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) in order to **sort the items by key**.

Given the following model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the following instances:

```
var first = new MyClass {UniqueId = "First", Value = "This"};
var second = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Second", Value = "That"};
var third = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Third", Value = "Foo"};
var fourth = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Fourth", Value = "Bar"};
```

### Using an OrderedDictionary

```
var dictionary = new OrderedDictionary()
{
    { first.UniqueId, first },
    { second.UniqueId, second },
    { third.UniqueId, first },
    { fourth.UniqueId, first },
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
```

This will keep the order of the added items. Output json is the following:

```
{
  "First": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Second": {
    "UniqueId": "Second",
    "Value": "That"
  },
  "Third": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Fourth": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  }
}
```

### Using a SortedDictionary

```
var first = new MyClass {UniqueId = "First", Value = "This"};
var second = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Second", Value = "That"};
var third = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Third", Value = "Foo"};
var fourth = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Fourth", Value = "Bar"};

var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, MyClass>
{
    { first.UniqueId, first },
    { second.UniqueId, second },
    { third.UniqueId, first },
    { fourth.UniqueId, first },
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
```

This will sort the items by key (`Fourth` is the 2nd item, not the 4th). Output json is the following:

```
{
  "First": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Fourth": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Second": {
    "UniqueId": "Second",
    "Value": "That"
  },
  "Third": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rui... I wasn't aware of the `SortedDictionary`... however, I need **ordered** rather than **sorted**.  The items need to be in the same order as they were inserted, hence I'm using `List<>`.  Maybe the way to go is to use the non-generic `OrderedDictionary` or `List<KeyValuePair<>>`

Comment: @freefaller stupid me, you're absolutely right. Added more details to my answer, I think an OrderedDictionary does the job.

Comment: Yes, `OrderedDictionary` does appear to work... although I'm always happier using strongly typed generic classes.  Never understood why MS took the decision not to give a generic version of it.  Never mind - thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @freefaller no problem :-) Yes I agree, it would be nice to have a generic version of `OrderedDictionary`

Answer (score 0):

A strongly-typed alternative to [OrderedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2) - use a `List<KeyValuePair<key, value>>` with a `Dictionary`.

So, given the following model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the following instances:

```
var first = new MyClass {UniqueId = "First", Value = "This"};
var second = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Second", Value = "That"};
var third = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Third", Value = "Foo"};
var fourth = new MyClass {UniqueId = "Fourth", Value = "Bar"};
```

Instead of creating and initializing the `Dictionary` like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>
{
    { first.UniqueId, first },
    { second.UniqueId, second },
    { third.UniqueId, first },
    { fourth.UniqueId, first },
};
```

We can create and initialize a `KeyValuePair` list and then create the `Dictionary`:

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>(first.UniqueId, first),
    new KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>(second.UniqueId, second),
    new KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>(third.UniqueId, third),
    new KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>(fourth.UniqueId, fourth),
};

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>(pairs);
```

This will keep the order of the items added to the `KeyValuePair` list. Serializing the `Dictionary`:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
```

Output json is the following:

```
{
  "First": {
    "UniqueId": "First",
    "Value": "This"
  },
  "Second": {
    "UniqueId": "Second",
    "Value": "That"
  },
  "Third": {
    "UniqueId": "Third",
    "Value": "Foo"
  },
  "Fourth": {
    "UniqueId": "Fourth",
    "Value": "Bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a lot of overkill... having to have a list that is put into a dictionary, etc. Thank you for your efforts, but I'll stick with the OrderedDictionary

Comment: @freefaller yep OrderedDictionary would be my first choice as well